# How to achieve array-symmetric two-column exchange?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage

We represent the image as a two-dimensional array. If you want to achieve vertical mirroring of the image, we need to symmetrically swap the columns of the two-dimensional array.
But in the teacher's code, why is the row of the array exchanged? And the result is correct.

```
    private void mirror() {
        // TODO
        for(int i = 0; i < dimX()/2; i++) {
            int[] col = pixels[i];                   
            pixels[i] = pixels[dimX()-i-1];
            pixels[dimX()-i-1] = col;
        }
    }
```

All code:

```
package ubung;

import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Die Klasse Bildbearbeitung laedt eine Bilddatei und fuehrt 
 * abhaengig von gewaehlten Optionen eine Reihe von 
 * Bildmanipulationen aus. 
 */
public class Bildbearbeitung {
    private int[][] pixels;

    /**
     * Konstruktor fuer die Klasse Bildbearbeitung, die eine Bilddatei einliest
     * und das zweidimensionale Pixel-Array pixels befuellt.
     * @param file Einzulesende Bilddatei
     */
    private Bildbearbeitung(String file) {
        try {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(file));
            pixels = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];
            for(int i = 0; i < dimX(); i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < dimY(); j++)
                    pixels[i][j] = img.getRGB(i, j);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }   

    private int dimX(){
        return pixels.length;
    }

    private int dimY(){
        if(dimX() == 0)
            return 0;
        return pixels[0].length;
    }

    /** 
     * Diese Funktion schreibt den Inhalt des Pixelarrays in die
     * Datei 'ausgabe.png'. Falls diese Datei nicht vorhanden ist, 
     * wird sie angelegt. Eine vorhandene Datei wird eventuell ueberschrieben!
     */
    private void save(String option){
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(dimX(), dimY(), 3);
        for(int i = 0; i < dimX(); i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < dimY(); j++)
                img.setRGB(i, j, pixels[i][j]);

        try {
            File outputfile = new File("ausgabe-" + option + ".png");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    /**
     * Diese Funktion nimmt einen ARGB-Wert und wandelt ihn in 
     * ein vierelementiges Array um, dass die einzelnen Bytes 
     * als int-Komponenten enthaelt. 
     * @param ARGB Integre Darstellung eines Pixels mit 4 Byte
     * Information: alpha-rot-gruen-blau
     * @return 4-elementiges Array [alpha, red, green, blue]
     */
    private int[] getColors(int ARGB) {
        // TODO nur das hier?
        int alpha = (ARGB >> 24) & 255;    // 按二进制形式把所有的数字向右移动对应的位数，低位移出(舍弃)，高位的空位补符号位，即正数补零，负数补1. 
        int red = (ARGB >> 16) & 255;
        int green = (ARGB >> 8) & 255;
        int blue = ARGB & 255;
        int[] array = {alpha,red,green,blue};
        return array;
    }

    /**
     * Ein vierelementiges Array mit kleinen (< 1 byte) int-Werten 
     * wird zu einem einzigen 4 byte Integer zusammengesetzt. 
     * @param array 4-elementiges Array
     * @return Eine Integerdarstellung einer Farbe in ARGB-Format.
     */
    private int setColors(int[] array) {
        int alpha = array[0] << 24;
        int red = array[1] << 16;
        int green = array[2] << 8;
        int blue = array[3];
        return alpha | red | green | blue;
    }

    /**
     * Das Bild wird hier rotiert und n*90 Grad.
     * @param n Anzahl der Vierteldrehungen.
     */
    private void rotate(int n) {
        if (n<=0){
            return;
        }
        int[][] pixelsTemp = new int[dimY()][dimX()];
        for(int j = 0; j < dimY(); j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < dimX(); i++) {
                pixelsTemp[j][dimX()-1-i] = pixels[i][j];           }
            }

        pixels = pixelsTemp;
        rotate(n-1);
    }

    /**
     * Die Farben werden invertiert: Farbe = (255-Farbe)
     */
    private void invert() {
        // TODO
        for(int i = 0; i < dimX(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < dimY(); j++){
                int[] array = getColors(pixels[i][j]);
                //array[0] = (byte)(255-array[0]);
                array[1] = (255-array[1]);
                array[2] = (255-array[2]);
                array[3] = (255-array[3]);
                pixels[i][j] = setColors(array);
            }
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Das Bild wird vertikal gespiegelt
     */
    private void mirror() {
        // TODO
        for(int i = 0; i < dimX()/2; i++) {
            int[] col = pixels[i];                   
            pixels[i] = pixels[dimX()-i-1];
            pixels[dimX()-i-1] = col;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Hilfsfunktion zum Zugriff, die Randpunkten gueltige 
     * nullwertige Nachbarn zuweist.
     */ 
    private int getPixel(int i, int j) {
        if(i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= dimX() || j >= dimY())
            return 0;
        return pixels[i][j];
    }

    /**
     * Diese Funktion betrachtet zu jedem Pixel seine Nachbarschaft, 
     * summiert gewichtet diese Menge auf und skaliert sie
     * @param filter 3x3 Umgebungsgewichte
     */ 
    private void meanFilter(double[] filter, double factor) {
        int[][] pixelsTemp = new int[dimX()][dimY()];
        for(int i = 0; i < dimX(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < dimY(); j++){
                double[] sum = {0.,0.,0.,0.};
                int[] sumInt = new int[4];
                for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
                    sum[col] += filter[0]*getColors(getPixel(i-1,j-1))[col];
                    sum[col] += filter[1]*getColors(getPixel(i-1,j))[col];
                    sum[col] += filter[2]*getColors(getPixel(i-1,j+1))[col];
                    sum[col] += filter[3]*getColors(getPixel(i,j-1))[col];
                    sum[col] += filter[4]*getColors(getPixel(i,j))[col];
                    sum[col] += filter[5]*getColors(getPixel(i,j+1))[col];
                    sum[col] += filter[6]*getColors(getPixel(i+1,j-1))[col];
                    sum[col] += filter[7]*getColors(getPixel(i+1,j))[col];
                    sum[col] += filter[8]*getColors(getPixel(i+1,j+1))[col];
                    sumInt[col] = (int)(sum[col]*factor);
                }
                pixelsTemp[i][j] = setColors(sumInt);
            }
        }
        pixels = pixelsTemp;
    }


    /** 
     * Gaussfilter
     */ 
    private void gauss(){
        double[] filter = {1,2,1,2,4,2,1,2,1};
        meanFilter(filter, 1.0/16.0);
    }

    /** 
     * Blurfilter/ Lowpassfilter
     */
    private void lpf(){
        double[] filter = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};
        meanFilter(filter,1.0/9.0);
    }

    /** 
     * Hochpassfilter 1
     */
    private void hpf1(){
        double[] filter = {0,-1,0,-1,4,-1,0,-1,0};
        meanFilter(filter,1.0);
    }

    /** 
     * Hochpassfilter 2
     */
    private void hpf2(){
        double[] filter = {-1,-1,-1,-1,9,-1,-1,-1,-1};
        meanFilter(filter,1.0);
    }

    /** 
     * Medianfilter
     */ 
    private void medianFilter(){
        //TODO
        int[][] pixelsTemp = new int[dimX()][dimY()];
        for(int i = 0; i < dimX(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < dimY(); j++){
                int[] values = new int[4];
                for(int col = 0; col < 4; col++){
                    int[] arrayMedian = new int[5];
                    arrayMedian[0] = getColors(getPixel(i,j))[col];
                    arrayMedian[1] = getColors(getPixel(i-1,j))[col];
                    arrayMedian[2] = getColors(getPixel(i+1,j))[col];
                    arrayMedian[3] = getColors(getPixel(i,j-1))[col];
                    arrayMedian[4] = getColors(getPixel(i,j+1))[col];
                    Arrays.sort(arrayMedian);
                    values[col] = arrayMedian[2];
                }
                pixelsTemp[i][j] = setColors(values);
            }
        }
        pixels = pixelsTemp;
    }

    /** 
     * Fuegt auf n Pixeln Rauschen hinzu.
     */ 
    private void jitter(int n) {
        Random random = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int x = random.nextInt(dimX());
            int y = random.nextInt(dimY());
            int[] colors = getColors(getPixel(x,y));
            colors[1] = random.nextInt(256);
            colors[2] = random.nextInt(256);
            colors[3] = random.nextInt(256);
            pixels[x][y] = setColors(colors);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int argCount = args.length;

        if(argCount == 0) {
            System.out.println("Verwendung: java Bildbearbeitung <FILE> [-options]");
            System.out.println("wobei options Folgendes umfasst:");
            System.out.println("\t -rot90 90 Grad rotieren");
            System.out.println("\t -rot180 180 Grad rotieren");
            System.out.println("\t -rot270 270 Grad rotieren");
            System.out.println("\t -i Farben invertieren");
            System.out.println("\t -m Horizontal spiegeln");
            System.out.println("\t -lpf Verwaschen");
            System.out.println("\t -median Median-Filter");
            System.out.println("\t -gauss Gauss-Filter");
            System.out.println("\t -hpf1 Hochpassfilter1");
            System.out.println("\t -hpf2 Hochpassfilter2");
            System.out.println("\t -jitter Verrauscht das Bild");
            return;
        }

        // load image as specified in first argument args[0]
        Bildbearbeitung bild = new Bildbearbeitung(args[0]);

        bild.save("raw");
        for(int i = 1; i < argCount; i++) {
            String option = args[i];
            System.out.println("Processing: " + option);
            if(option.equals("-rot90"))
                bild.rotate(1);
            else if(option.equals("-rot180"))
                bild.rotate(2);
            else if(option.equals("-rot270"))
                bild.rotate(3);
            else if(option.equals("-i"))
                bild.invert();
            else if(option.equals("-m"))
                bild.mirror();  
            else if(option.equals("-gauss"))
                bild.gauss();
            else if(option.equals("-median"))
                bild.medianFilter();
            else if(option.equals("-lpf"))
                bild.lpf();
            else if(option.equals("-jitter"))
                bild.jitter(50000);
            else if(option.equals("-hpf1"))
                bild.hpf1();
            else if(option.equals("-hpf2"))
                bild.hpf2();

            bild.save(""+i);
        }

        bild.save("done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not swapping the rows; review the declaration of pixels:
pixels = new int[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];

Width / X values are the first [], representing whole columns.

Compare the section switching it around to the part initializing it.
You may want to step through the function to see it work.